# Bulk update with JpaRepository

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I want to optimize calls to db and create a thread safe update.
Class model:

```java
        class Order{
            private Long id;
            private BigDecimal firstFee;
            private BigDecimal secondFee;
        }
```

This is a call to db which works fine and I think does what I need.

```sql
    UPDATE order
    SET first_fee = v.first_fee,
        second_fee = v.second_fee
    FROM (
             SELECT *
             FROM unnest(ARRAY[3393007]::bigint[], ARRAY[333]::numeric[], ARRAY[333]::numeric[]) AS v(id, first_fee, second_fee)
         ) AS v
    WHERE order.id = v.id;
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to complete a proper native query.
What I am able to achieve is a working solution for values only if every element is not null

```java
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "UPDATE order ao SET " +
        "first_fee = v.firstFee, " +
        "second_fee = v.secondFee " +
        "FROM (SELECT id, firstFee, secondFee FROM unnest(ARRAY[:ids], ARRAY[:firstFees], ARRAY[:secondFees]) AS v(id, firstFees, secondFees)) v " +
        "WHERE ao.id = v.id", nativeQuery = true)
void updateOrderFeesInBulk(List<Long> ids, List<BigDecimal> firstFees, List<BigDecimal> secondFees);
```

If firstFees or secondFees contains a null, I get:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
```

Stack: java, spring, postgres

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing Lists properties separately, you should create a List of *Order* objects and then use can simply call the repo.saveAll(orders) to save the List of orders.

Refer the following example
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-batch-inserts

Comment: My goal is to achieve parallelization and outsource it's handling to the db. Multiple other jobs will edit other fields (let's call it thirdFee etc.) and I don't want to handle it on myself.